# possible solution for "You cannot call addFields after you've already loaded the data" - error

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I've seen this error and researched it and this is not happening because of a test. If you're getting this error because of some unit tests look at this [Bob Buzzards Blog here](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-visualforce-bindings-and.html)

My problem is different. The error actually makes sense here. I've figured out the problem but I'm trying to brainstorm some solutions.

So the setup is that I have a Salesforce visualforce page that has a standardcontroller to Leads. In this VF page I've included( with ) another visualforce page which is also attached to Leads with and extension controller that includes the addFields in its constructor.

```
//Page Outer
<apex:page standardController="Leads">
    <apex:include pageName="inner"></apex:include>

</apex:page>

//page inner
<apex:page id="inner" standardController="Leads" extensions="leadsExt">

</apex:page>


public class leadsExt
{
   public leadsExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController))
   {
       List<String> customFields = new List<String>{'some__customField__c'};
       stdController.addFields(customFields);
   }
}
```

So if in page outer I include a form with any input element that links to the leads object. It'll throw this error. If I include the  tag before the input element then it works fine. I know it's because the apex:inputfield loads the current object so the leadsExt now is acting on a data thats already loading and adding a field to an instantiated object is not allowed.

What is some work around that I can do that would allow me to put the input element before the include tag?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make sure that the outer page loads `some__customField__c`. You could do that by adding the same controller extension to that page or writing one that only adds the field if necessary. Or you could put hidden input fields referencing `some__customField__c` in both pages if that seems more logical.